# Как правильно управлять стилями?

Tags: css3, анимация, javascript, формулы

Помогите новичку JavaScript управлять стилями...

Правильно ли управлять стилями с использованием массива
`List[i] = document.getElementById("divideid" + i);` ?

Если поподробнее...

```
var ListLongY, ListHistoryMemoryLast, ListHistoryMemoryCurrent, List = new Array(4);

for (var i = 1; i < List.length; i++) {
    List[i] = document.getElementById("divideid" + i);
    console.log(List[i] + " in " + i);
};

MenuButton = function () {
    ListHistoryMemoryCurrent = arguments[1];
    ListLongY = arguments[2];
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) console.log(arguments[i]);
    for (var i = 0; i < List.length; i++) {
        List[i].style.zIndex = "0";
        List[i].style.display = "none";
        if (i == ListHistoryMemoryCurrent) {
            List[i].style.zIndex = "1";
            List[i].style.display = "block";
            List[i].style.marginTop = ListLongY;
        }
        else if (i == ListHistoryMemoryLast) {
            List[i].style.zIndex = "0";
            List[i].style.display = "block";
            List[i].style.marginTop = "0";
        };
    };
    for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        setTimeout(ListDownAnim(ListLongY/5, i, ListHistoryMemoryCurrent, ListLongY), 1000 * i);
    };
};
ListDownAnim = function () {
    ListHistoryMemoryCurrent = arguments[3];
    ListLongY = arguments[4];
    for (var i = arguments[1] * arguments[2]; i < arguments[1]*(arguments[2] + 1); i++) {
        List[ListHistoryMemoryCurrent].style.marginTop = ListLongY;
    };
}
/* MenuButton(1, 1000); number_of_button, lenght_of__current_list */
```

Answer (score 1):

Нет, правильно управлять стилями, присваивая и убирая классы.

Comment: у него там анимация(хоть и кривая), может есть причина не использовать css3 анимацию